# "Session times out after" profile setting in metadata api

Tags: metadata-api

Is it possible to update the value of the "Session times out after" value for the profile?

[image]

I didn't see it in the [Profile metadata API developer's guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm).

Comment: I don't believe you can set it via the API. I assume it could be a potential security issue if a user could modify there session settings programmatically (you know what they say about assuming though)